# converting a dictionary with unknown value types to json

Tags: c#

I wrote the code below to convert a dictionary to a json string.
The catch here is that the dictionary values could be of various types
string, int, string[], int[], float[], ...
I tried using generics, but I get a compile error where I do GetParamList because it expects me to specify the actual type.
I was wondering if there is a way that I can avoid putting lots of if/else conditions to achieve what I want.

```
private static string GetParamList<T>(object values)
{
    if (values.GetType().Equals(typeof(string[])) )
    {
        string[] res = (string[])values;
        if (values.GetType().Equals(typeof(string[])))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!res[i].ToString().StartsWith("\""))
                {
                    res[i] = string.Format("\"{0}\"", res[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return string.Join(",", res);
    }
    else if (values.GetType().Equals(typeof(string)))
    {
        return string.Format("\"{0}\"", values);
    }
    else// array of numbers:
    {
        string[] res = ((T[])values).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray<string>();
        return string.Join(",", res);
    }
}

private static string dictToJson(Dictionary<string, object> data)
{
    List<string> entries = new List<string>();
    foreach (var entry in data)
    {
        Type T = entry.Value.GetType();
        entries.Add(string.Format("\"{0}\": {1}", entry.Key, GetParamList<T>(entry.Value)));
    }
    return "{" + string.Join(",", entries.ToArray<string>()) + "}";
}
```

Comment: Generics don't work that way. They are compile time construct. Does compiler know value of entry.Value.GetType()? No, it doesn't.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel.  You should use an existing JSON serializer.

Comment: In particular, you aren't actually generating valid JSON.

Comment: Rather than writing a custom (likely inefficient and error prone) JSON library, why not use [an existing one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)?

Comment: Totally agree with @SLaks! Use the existing one.

Comment: Also, why are you using generics in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is made here:

```
Type T = entry.Value.GetType();
```

What you're doing here is *not* getting a generic parameter - instead, you're getting the object of class `Type` which represents the parameter you want. Generics are designed to work with a type known at compile time, so that the JIT Compiler can create the definition of the class on the fly for you. You thus cannot pass in the `Type` object as a generic parameter.

There are, however, several ways to get around this.

The first and easiest is to have a factory method which can perform generic inference, and pass the generic parameter as `dynamic`. This will force the CLR to hold off until runtime to decide what type to use, and then use the best matched type for the parameters. Not that this will *not* work with your code as is - generic inferencing demands you use `T` as the type of a parameter in addition to the generic type, such as:

```
private static string GetParamList<T>(T[] values)
```

The second would be to metacode the operation and compile the call using the `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace, which could be significantly more verbose:

```
var val = Expression.Constant(entry.Value);
var method = typeof(MyType)    // Where MyType is the type containing "GetParamList"
    .GetMethod("GetParamList")
    .MakeGenericMethod(t);     // Where t is the desired type
string result = Expression
    // Lambda turns an expression tree into an expressiong tree with an explicit delegate signature
    .Lambda<Func<String>>(
        Expression.Call(null, method, val))    // "Call the method against nothing (it's static) and pass in val (which is a constant in this case)"
    .Compile()  // This compiles our expression tree
    .Invoke();  // Run the method
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it the hard way, try this.

```
public List<Event_Log> GetAll()
{
 List<Event_Log> result = new List<Event_Log>();
    //add result collection here...
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the OP is using ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: You can easily change the return result as List<Dictionary<string, object> which is the same thing. Use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Comment: How is a JSON string the same as `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`? Even the `Json` method itself is a part of the MVC's `Controller` class not available outside of MVC.

Comment: I'm using asp with 3.5 clr. Which package is the code above using?

Comment: Alright I change the code for 3.5, you can receive the List colleciton above as json

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for recommending "Newtonsoft.Json".
I used that package this way and all the problems are solved:

```
private static string dictToJson(Dictionary<string, object> data)
{

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None,
        TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple
    });

    return json;
}
```